# The *. pst file cannot be found

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2013

We have been trying to remove all accounts from Outlook 2013 and start from scratch. We deleted everything in the `~/Documents/Outlook Files` directory . Now we are receiving the following message:

> The file drive \path\filename.pst could not be found

How can we let Outlook know that we want to start from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Control Panel`, then `Mail`:

[image]

Click `Data Files`

[image]

From here, you can delete your old data file reference (You may need to add a new one first)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Steps

Here is one method that worked for us.

1. Go to Control Panel > Mail.
2. Choose Show Profiles.
3. Highlight the listed profile (e.g. Outlook), choose Remove, and click Apply.
4. The next time you open Outlook, create a new profile.

## Screen Captures

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]